# How to pull specific tag data from XML using Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, xml-parsing

I have an XML file store on the IIS server. I am attempting to get the value of the `<amount>` within the `<TotalNetCharge>` tag.

Here is the tag that resides in the file location:

```
<TotalNetCharge>
<Currency>USD</Currency> 
<Amount>92.33</Amount> 
</TotalNetCharge>
```

I've tried using the XML in a variable and also reading it in from a file. Neither works. Here is the code:

```
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
'oXML.LoadXML(SOAPResponse) 
oXML.LoadXML("D:\myfile\XMLReply.xml")
For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("//TotalNetCharge/Amount")
    Response.Write "test"
Next

Set oXML = Nothing
```

Nothing gets written to the screen, so I'm assuming the data is not being loaded because if it were the loop would be entered and "test" written to screen. I also tried loading the commented out portion (SOAPResponse) which I know has data in it because I Response.Write it to the screen. Anyone? 2 days on this nonsense.

Update, here is the replacement code that worked.

```
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLDoc.async = False
objXMLDoc.loadXML(SOAPResponse)

Dim TransactionDetail, CustomerTransactionId

Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("ServiceType")
For Each Node In NodeList
   Response.write(Node.text & "<br>")
Next
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TotalNetCharge")
For Each Node In NodeList
   Response.write(Node.text & "<br>")
Next
```

Comment: If you figured this out, then you should answer your own question. You'll then be able to get upvotes for it.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong object method;

- [loadXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is for loading an XML document directly from a string, not from a file or URL
- [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you want for loading from a URL

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the reply. I also tried loading the string, as you can see the commented out portion 'oXML.LoadXML(SOAPResponse), that SOAPResponse string does in fact contain all the XML data, I can see it when I do a Response.Write, but no matter what I cannot get access to any of the nodes.

Comment: After messing with this for hours I finally am able to get the data. I had to change the .SelectNodes to GetElementsByTagName. That and I dim the TotalNetCharge and Amount, also got rid of the // in front of them. Not really sure what actually fixed the issue, but fairly certain it was the swap of GetElementsByTagName for SelectNodes. I'll post in the new code.

Comment: @ArlenHarris: write that up as an answer, then you can accept it yourself in a couple of days.